powershell calling pow() in function
I want my pow2($a,$n) function to call [math]::pow($a,$n) so I wrote this :
function pow2($a,$n) {
    return [math]::pow($a,$n)
}

But when I call it I get this error :
PS C:\> pow2(2,10)
Cannot convert argument "x", with value: "System.Object[]", for "Pow" to type "System.Double": "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of
type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Double"."
At C:\Users\sebastien.mansfeld\OneDrive - PLURIAD – Groupe
Media-Participations\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:18 char:9
+     return [math]::pow($a,$n)
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

PS C:\> 

I expect this result :
PS C:\> pow2(2,10)
1024
PS C:\> 


Remove the brackets when calling your function. pow2 2 10. Powershell uses spaces to separate parameters. The way you're calling it makes Powershell send an array

In short: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked like shell commands - foo arg1 arg2 - not like C# methods - foo('arg1', 'arg2').
If you use , to separate arguments, you'll construct an array that a command sees as a single argument.
See the linked duplicates for details.

You are Calling It Wrong.
Function Parameters in Powershell are called WITHOUT the parenthesis.
pow2 2 10 will work
Also you don't need return
